# Why can't I get anywhere near the medal times for survival mode?

Tags: serious-sam-3-bfe, serious-sam-the-second-encounter

I've been playing a bit of survival mode in *Serious Sam HD: The Second Encounter* and *Serious Sam 3: BFE*, but I'm having a lot of trouble even getting a bronze medal time, let alone get a silver or gold.

I managed to eek out a bronze time for the *Death from Above* map in *TSE*. However, I'm not getting anywhere in any of the other maps—my best time for *Kleer Base* in *TSE* is 1:50, and the bronze medal time is 3:00. On every other map I play, I seem to miss the medal times by a large margin.

I suspect there's something systematically wrong with the way I'm playing. I obviously can't describe my playing style in full detail, but I will update this question with more information as needed.

---

### Edit 1

Just got a 4:06 time on my first attempt at *Deserted* in *BFE*, a map that is wider open and has fewer and more powerful enemies positioned far away from Sam, especially for the first few minutes. The *Death from Above* map mentioned above is similarly wide open, though enemies are positioned a bit closer.

This is telling us that the problem is in close-quarters combat and large groups of smaller enemies. Any ideas?